# drop dataframe from dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have `toy_df`

`toy_df = pd.DataFrame(['animal':['cat','cat','cat','dog']`

```
   animal
0     cat
1     cat
2     cat
3     dog
```

i'm using `toy_df_4 = toy_df[toy_df.animal == 'dog']`

```
   animal
3     dog
```

how i can drop certain daaframe `toy_df_4` from general `toy_df`

i have tried `toy df - toy_df_4` but this error

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

this dataframes are toy so in real dataset i have dataframes with many conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpliest here is invert condition for get not matched rows by `dog`:

```
toy_df = pd.DataFrame({'animal':['cat','cat','cat','dog']})

toy_df_5 = toy_df[toy_df.animal != 'dog']
print (toy_df_5)
  animal
0    cat
1    cat
2    cat
```

But if really need drop by index value of filtered DataFrame:

```
toy_df_4 = toy_df[toy_df.animal == 'dog']
toy_df_5 = toy_df.drop(toy_df_4.index)
print (toy_df_5)
  animal
0    cat
1    cat
2    cat
```

Answer (score 2):

```
toy_df = pd.DataFrame({'animal':['cat','cat','cat','dog']})
toy_df4 = toy_df[toy_df.animal=='dog']

df = toy_df.merge(toy_df_4, how='outer', indicator=True).loc[lambda x: x['_merge']=='left_only'].reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.drop('_merge', axis=1)
```

output:

```
    animal
0    cat
1    cat
2    cat
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use [`pandas.DataFrame.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

```
toy_df = pd.DataFrame(['animal':['cat','cat','cat','dog']
toy_df_4 = toy_df[toy_df.animal == 'dog']
toy_df = toy_df[~toy_df.isin(toy_df_4)].dropna()

print(toy_df)
  animal
0    cat
1    cat
2    cat
```